# How to put JavaScript and CSS files in browser cache?

Tags: javascript, performance, caching, coldfusion

I have put the cache clear code in a .cfm page for security reasons. The cache clear code is

```
<cfheader name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="Pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfheader name="Expires" value="#GetHttpTimeString(Now()-1)#">
```

Now for every request it 
fetching all the JavaScript, CSS and image files from server which decrease the speed of my site. Is there any way in ColdFusion or JavaScript to keep the JavaScript, CSS and image files in cache to increase performance?

Comment: Remove the headers ? oO

Comment: @Virus721 I can not remove the headers for security reason.

Comment: What do you mean by security reason ?

Comment: @Virus721 want to prevent page caching.

Comment: Ho i see you want to cache everything but HTML. Well i've an idea. Make all your HTML pages .php pages. This way the browser will re-download them everytime a user loads the page since the HTML is generated on the fly, the file will be considered modified.

Comment: @Virus721: No. It makes no difference to caching whether the file extension is `.php` or `.html` or whether the files were dynamically generated or not.

Comment: So...you want to cache the page...but you don't want to cache the page?

Comment: The CF pages and the images/scripts/styles all come in separate requests, so you can set different headers on all of them, and they won't affect each other - so turning off cache on your .cfm page will not turn off cache on your images. Have you confirmed that you're not caching the static files by watching the network requests and the headers on those files?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're on Apache) Enable your mod_expires and customize your cache conditions in your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault “access plus 1 second”
    ExpiresByType text/css “access plus 7 days”
    ExpiresByType image/jpg “access plus 7 days”
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes we are using Apache, Could you please explain me in which file i should put this code.

Comment: this script would go in your .htaccess file. If it does not work seek further help from this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11622555/2623144