# htaccess browser caching not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

My .htaccess file ignores the whole browser caching stuff. I have multiple domains on the same server and in one of them, the same code is working fine. My testing tool is [WebPageTest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org).

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
   <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css text/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-javascript
      AddType image/svg+xml .svg
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 12 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 4 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/htm "access plus 4 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 2 days"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

I read many topics about this issue but mostly they are saying the mod_expires module is deactivated. I checked my `phpinfo()` output and this module is already loaded (also mod_deflate and mod_filter).

In the following thread [htaccess caching not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513791/htaccess-caching-not-working) Anthony Hatzopoulos gives an awesome answer and I used the [REDbot](https://redbot.org/) site to analyze my HTTP Header. It always shows

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

If I set the cache control manually by using `header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");` the HTTP Header looks fine, but the browser caching rules from the .htaccess are still ignored.

I don't understand why the Cache-Control is using `no-store, no-cache, ...` as default and where I can change it. In addition I noticed that the mod_header module isn't listed in my `phpinfo()` output and the `FileMatch` tag cause an internal server error without the `ifModule mod_header` check. But if that's the issue, why is the same script working on the other domain?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit from 21.06.2017:**

I forgot to say that we are using an CDN (Cloudflare). I analzyed more Headers with REDbot and the Cache-Control seems to be correct (png, `Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000`). In my WebPageTest result it shows always `WARNING - (4.0 hours) - (...).png`. Either the CDN is overwriting the header or the testresult is just wrong?!

Comment: Have you enabled the expire module?

Comment: The `mod_expires` module is in my "Loaded Modules" list in my phpinfo() output.